# Xamarin Forms, Onedrive not working in iOS but working on Android and UWP

Tags: xamarin.forms

I hope can someone can help me with setting up connecting to OneDrive form a Xamarin Forms App.
I know there are lot of examples that can be found but these seem to be outdated. None of them work anymore.

Therefore I tried Xamarin.OneDrive which works on UWP and Android but not on iOS.

The steps I took on iOS:

```
Added 'com.microsoft.adalcache' to the keychain group in Entitlements.plist

Added the following code in appdelegate.cs

    public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication app, NSUrl url, NSDictionary options)
    {
        Xamarin.OneDrive.Connector.SetAuthenticationContinuationEventArgs(url);
        return true;
    }

Added the following to plist.info with the correct Bundlename and Appid

<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string><BUNDLENAME></string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string><APPID></string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>

Under iOS Bundle Signing I selected Manual Provisioning and selected Entitlements.plist in Custom Entitlements
```

Run running the application on a simulator or on a physical device results in the following error being shown:

```
System.Exception: Internal Server Error
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: viewController
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.AcquireTokenInteractiveParameterBuilder.WithParentActivityOrWindow (UIKit.UIViewController viewController) [0x00003] in :0
at Xamarin.OneDrive.DependencyImplementation.GetAuthResult (Microsoft.Identity.Client.IPublicClientApplication client, Xamarin.OneDrive.Configs configs) [0x00093] in <702bbb93f52d451c89c8adacbd52d653>:0
at Xamarin.OneDrive.Token.AcquireAsync () [0x00091] in <702bbb93f52d451c89c8adacbd52d653>:0
at Xamarin.OneDrive.Token.ConnectAsync () [0x000f0] in <702bbb93f52d451c89c8adacbd52d653>:0
at Xamarin.OneDrive.ConnectorHandler.InnerConnectionHandlerAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00161] in <702bbb93f52d451c89c8adacbd52d653>:0
```

I don't have a clue how to continue.

Can someone tell me how to get this working on iOS ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you know which line in your project caused this exception? There is an sample project [here](https://github.com/LeversonCarlos/Xamarin.OneDrive.Connector) in the github, you can add your id there to see if it works well.

Comment: Hi Jack, the error occurs when the following is called: await App.OneDrive.ConnectAsync().  I tried the Sample projects, this results in the same thing